# Terraform : Is there a better way to impersonate service accounts? Is it possible to use and output a provider in modules?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

The current way I am able to impersonate service accounts via terraform is by using lengthy declarations like these with multiple `provider` blocks. Not to mention I have to copy/paste this every time for each user/s.a/project...

```
provider "google" {
  alias  = "network_admin_impersonation"
  scopes = var.impersonation_info.of_network_admin.tier_1_scopes
}
data "google_service_account_access_token" "network-admin" {
  provider               = google.network_admin_impersonation
  target_service_account = google_service_account.network-admin.email
  scopes                 = var.impersonation_info.of_network_admin.tier_2_scopes
  lifetime               = "1200s"
}

provider "google" {
  alias        = "as_network_admin"
  access_token = data.google_service_account_access_token.network-admin.access_token
  region       = var.region
  zone         = var.zone
}
```

And to grant users the right to use this service account :

```
resource "google_service_account_iam_member" "network-admin-impersonators" {
  for_each = toset([
    for account in var.user_accs_impersonators_info.as_network_admin :
    "${account.acc_type}:${account.acc_details.email}"
  ])

  service_account_id = google_service_account.network-admin.name
  role               = "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator"
  member             = each.value
}
```

There must be a better way to do this that I am not seeing. Maybe via a module? But I read somewhere that it is generally a bad idea to use `provider` within modules... I would appreciate some guidance on this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the provider initialization syntax, which allows you to embed a provider's configuration block within another provider's configuration block.
So your configuration could look like this instead:

```
provider "google" {
    alias = "network_admin_impersonation"

    scopes = var.impersonation_info.of_network_admin.tier_1_scopes

    provider {
    access_token = data.google_service_account_access_token.network-admin.access_token
    region       = var.region
    zone         = var.zone
    }
}
```

Note that the `provider` block is nested within the `provider` block, and that it does not have an alias attribute.

edit:

I don't think you can. What you can do is create a provider configuration block with the token and pass it to the child
provider:

```
provider "google" {
alias = "network_admin_impersonation"

scopes = var.impersonation_info.of_network_admin.tier_1_scopes

provider {
    access_token = data.google_service_account_access_token.network-admin.access_token
    region       = var.region
    zone         = var.zone
}

provider "google" {
    alias = "as_network_admin"
}
}
```

Or you can just declare it all in the google provider:

```
provider "google" {
alias = "network_admin_impersonation"

scopes = var.impersonation_info.of_network_admin.tier_1_scopes
}

provider "google" {
alias = "as_network_admin"

access_token = data.google_service_account_access_token.network-admin.access_token
region       = var.region
zone         = var.zone
}
```

edit 2

You could use the count of the service account list to create the multiple provider blocks.
Pass the service account name as a variable to the module.

Example module

```
variable "service_accounts" {
type = list(string)
}

resource "google_service_account" "service_account" {
count = length(var.service_accounts)
name  = var.service_accounts[count.index]
}

data "google_service_account_access_token" "service_account" {
count = length(var.service_accounts)
provider = google.service_account
service_account = element(var.service_accounts, count.index)
scopes = var.impersonation_info.of_network_admin.tier_2_scopes
lifetime = "1200s"
}

provider "google" {
count = length(var.service_accounts)
alias = element(var.service_accounts, count.index)
scopes = var.impersonation_info.of_network_admin.tier_1_scopes

provider {
    access_token = element(data.google_service_account_access_token.service_account.*.access_token, count.index)
    region       = var.region
    zone         = var.zone
}
}

Example usage
module "impersonation" {
source = "./impersonation"
service_accounts = [
    "network_admin_service_account",
    "project_admin_service_account",
]
}
```

And you can use the following resources to grant permissions to the service accounts.

```
resource "google_iam_member" "service_account" {
count = length(var.service_accounts)
service_account_id = element(var.service_accounts, count.index)
role               = "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator"
member             = var.member
}
```

Comment: Do you think we can put this in a module for reuse without code duplication?

Comment: Also, how do you call the `access_token` here? `google.network_admin_impersonation.access_token` ?

Comment: If you're using the same provider configuration more than once in your configuration, you can define that configuration in a module and then call it multiple times.

Comment: The idea, is to create several "impersonations", `project_admin_impersonation`, `bigquery_admin_impersonation`, etc... and to pass those values (and the service accounts) as inputs to this module

Comment: Just look at my edit I think it's got all you need in it

Comment: Ok this is one way of granting several service_accounts impersonation via `access_token`. How do you create resources as that service account..?

In my case, I would just specify `provider = "as_network_admin` on the resources I'm trying to create, but here there is no alias that I can use

Comment: This code you gave doesn't really work... `provider = google.service_account` inside your  `data "google_service_account_access_token" "service_account"` doesn't really have a definition

Comment: Also, `alias` does not support variable interpolation or function calls. Sorry.
`│ Error: Function calls not allowed
│ On ../modules/data-products/...<redacted> line 91: Functions may not be called here.`

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly straightforward way to use service account impersonation to authenticate Terraform for Google Cloud.

The key is to grant yourself the IAM role of [Service Account Token Creator](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#token-creator-role). (Please note that this role is NOT given by default, even if you are the project owner.) And to use [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials)

First, set up the service account if you haven't done so.

```bash
export GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=`gcloud info --format="value(config.project)"` 
gcloud iam service-accounts create terraform \
    --description="Terraform Service Account" \
    --display-name="terraform"

export GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT=`gcloud iam service-accounts list --format="value(email)" \
 --filter=description:"Terraform Service Account"` 

 gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT \
    --member="serviceAccount:$GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT" \
    --role="roles/editor"
```

Then unset any previous GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS

```bash
unset GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS  
gcloud auth application-default login --no-launch-browser
```

Then setup the service account impersonation.

```bash
# Set up impersonation 
export USER_ACCOUNT_ID=`gcloud config get core/account` 
export GOOGLE_IMPERSONATE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT=$GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT

gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
    $GOOGLE_IMPERSONATE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT \
    --member="user:$USER_ACCOUNT_ID" \
    --role="roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator"
```

And off you go. You can try it with this code snippet.

```
#main.tf
resource "random_string" "this" {
  length  = 16
  upper   = false
  special = false
  numeric = false
}

resource "google_storage_bucket" "this" {
  name     = random_string.this.result
  location = "us-central1"
}
```